# anything like weak var for Closure

Tags: swift

How can i fix this code,
for not block an object

```
class EIUIBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    typealias HandleClosure = (UIBarButtonItem) -> Void
    fileprivate var handle: HandleClosure?
    init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, handle: HandleClosure? = nil) {
        self.handle = handle
        super.init()
        self.image = image
        self.style = style
        self.target = self
        self.action = #selector(buttonAction(_:))
    }
    // ...OtherCode...        
    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        handle?(sender)
    }
}
```

If I create this button as

```
EIUIBarButtonItem(image: myUIImage, style: .plain, handle: controller.buttonAction)
```

I bloked object `controller`. How I can do some like this? I need weak var for my handle

```
   weak var handle: HandleClosure?
```

or maybe anything like this (@unowned)

```
   EIUIBarButtonItem(image: myUIImage, style: .plain, handle: @unowned controller.buttonAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a reference to the `controller`'s method directly, wrap it in a closure.

```
... handle: { [weak controller] button in controller?.buttonAction(button) })
```

Comment: this will cause the programmer to remember that every time the button is initialized, you need to wrap the handler. but can something that will help to solve the problem in the inner of the class